# Removing option tabs that are not contained in a select tag

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, html-select

I have a page that displays a table containing select boxes, but at the bottom there are options being displayed that are not a part of the actual table. In Safari and Chrome the options don't show because they are not contained in a select but in Firefox they show like regular text.

```
<table>
    <tr><td><select><option>1</option><option>2</option></select></td></tr>
    <tr><td><select><option>1</option><option>2</option></select></td></tr>
    <tr><td><select><option>1</option><option>2</option></select></td></tr>
    <option>1</option><option>2</option> <!-- I WANT TO REMOVE THIS -->
</table>
```

I am thinking I could use jQuery to grab the options that don't have a select parent. Is this assumption correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this -

```
$('option').each(function(){
  if($(this).closest('select').length < 1){
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

Demo  `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/r7GgV/